# Is there an Open Source Version of Facebook Ads manager?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, controls, ads

I am running a small community site and I want to have an ads manage similar to that which is on ravelry.com or Facebook where advertisers can create their own ads. I'm wondering if there are any open source platforms that would be easily tied into a Wordpress site that would allow for end users to manage their own ad spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this open source project that serves my purposes. Very impressive so far: http://orbitopenadserver.com/